# Comparisons between life in Eden and life in the wilderness

Tags: commentaries, chasidut-hasidism, parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies

I'm looking for sources comparing the Israelites' life in the wilderness to life in Eden.

The Chassidic understanding of the sin of the m'raglim is that they wanted to continue their wholly spiritual existence in the wilderness, with no need to work the land or weave clothes, and able to concentrate solely on their relationship with the Divine. Some modern d'rashot compare this to Eden, eg [here](https://outorah.org/p/843/) and [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5776-shlach/) – but is there an 'original' source connecting that stage of Israelite life to life in Eden?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sefas Emes [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefat_Emet%2C_Exodus%2C_Beshalach.15.4) it was as though the Jews in the desert had reentered Gan Eden, symbolized by the Manna:

> שדור המדבר הי' הלחם שלהם מבחי' התורה ממש. ונק' לחם מן השמים. והי' מעין
> הכנה ראשונה. דכ' ויניחהו בגן עדן. [רמז לדבר כזרע גד לבן ר"ת וס"ת גן
> עדן]. אח"כ כ' פן ישלח ידו כו' מעה"ח כו' ויגרש כו' להט החרב כו' לשמור
> כו' דרך עץ החיים. והיינו דמאן דנצח לחויא כו'. לכן אחר יצ"מ היו בנ"י
> מוכנים לעץ החיים כמ"ש אני אמרתי כו' ובני עליון כולכם. וניתן להם לחם
> שמה"ש אוכלין.

Similarly, he says the first Shabbos observance in Marah was on par with the original Shabbos in Gan Eden:

> ואמרו חז"ל אילו שמרו בנ"י שבת ראשונה לא שלטה בהם אומה. דכ' ויהי ביום
> הז' יצאו כו' ויבא עמלק. פרשנו שבת ראשונה ממש. כמו שהי' אז בשבת בראשית.
> ויניחהו בגן. והוא עיקר השביתה והרצון שעלה לפניו ית"ש. ובאמת בכל שב"ק
> יש הארה מזה. לכן יורדת נשמה יתירה מג"ע. ונק' מנוחה. אך אז במדבר הי'
> מתוקן לגמרי. ונק' שבת ראשונה.